# Access data on an unencrypted SD card

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, encryption

Having recently gotten a drone with a camera, I find myself wanting to drop the SD card into my device to grab / share some raw photos / images, intended of just screen shots. The problem that I am having is that my android device is encrypted, and is asking to encrypt my drone's as card every time it is inserted.

On insert - I am prompted with the message ( would you like to encrypt this device ) to which I answer NO, the next toast message is SD card unmounted.

Every time I click mount, I am again prompted to encrypt the card, and if I click no it is automatically unmounted.

> The card is a standard FAT32 format - how can I mount the card and view my footage without reformatting / encrypting the card?

I am running an LG G4 (VS986) running Android 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

You could try connecting the sd card through a usb card reader and otg cable, but I'm not sure an encrypted android install will mount an unencrypted sd card. It introduces vulnerabilities which kinda defeats the purpose of encrypting your device to begin with.

Comment: I can try that at a later time - but it is kind of ridiculous that it will not even mount a standard FAT32 formatted device. My laptop is 100% encrypted, but I can still plug in a flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

If the device is encrypted, you can try turning off the encryption in the settings. Then turn the phone off and remove the battery. While the battery is removed put the sd card into the phone. Then replace the battery and boot up the phone. It should mount the sd card with no problems (at least it did on my device). If all else fails, try a USB sd card reader on an OTG cable. It should be recognized as a USB device and should not want to encrypt it, since it just encrypts the sd card.
Hope this helps!